# Two margin woes

Tags: spacing, sectioning, page-breaking, margins

I have two problems with my margins. One is that when I print the margins, I can't seem to get them to come out properly. I have

```
\usepackage[top = 1in, bottom = 1in, left = 1.5in, right = 1in]{geometry}
```

at the top of the document, and it looks right when it's on the screen, but it never seems to come out properly when I print.

Also, I need to change it so that on pages where I start a new section it makes the top margin be two inches. Does anyone know how to do these things?

Comment: If you are printing from Acrobat Reader, be sure to turn off any page scale option.

Comment: Which document class are you using? For your second question, when you say "new section", do you mean sectional unit built with the `\chapter` command?

Comment: \documentclass[12pt, letterpaper]{article}

I've just been throwing in sections with the \section*{sectiontitle} command.

Comment: From your description, it seems that every `\section` command starts a new page; is that so? If this is the case, which code are you using for this purpose?

Comment: I've been typing \newpage before each section.

Comment: Also, turning off the page scaling on Adobe does seem to have solved the problem. Thanks for your help! In hindsight, I shoulda figured that out...

Answer (score 5):

According to the comments, the first problem was solved simply by turning off page scaling on Acrobat Reader (as suggested by **JLDiaz**).

For your second question, you can use the [`titlesec`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/titlesec) package; defining `\sectionbreak` to be `\clearpage`, you can make `\section` to automatically start a new page, and redefining `\section` with the help of `\titleformat` you can add the required additional vertical space before the titles. A little example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[top = 1in, bottom = 1in, left = 1.5in, right = 1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{lipsum}% just to generate text for the example

\newcommand\sectionbreak{\clearpage}
\titleformat{\section}
  {\vspace*{1in}\normalfont\Large\bfseries}{\thesection}{1em}{}

\begin{document}

\section{Test Section One}
\lipsum[1-12]
\section{Test Section Two}
\lipsum[1-12]

\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

Without using the `titlesec` package, you can redefine `\section` (as implemented in `article.cls`) to add `\clearpage` (to start a new page) and `\vspace*{1in}` (to add the required extra vertical space). Here's an example showing the required redefinition:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[top = 1in, bottom = 1in, left = 1.5in, right = 1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum}% just to generate text for the example

\makeatletter
\renewcommand\section{\clearpage\vspace*{1in}\@startsection {section}{1}{\z@}%
                                   {0ex \@minus -.2ex}%
                                   {2.3ex \@plus.2ex}%
                                   {\normalfont\Large\bfseries}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\section{Test Section One}
\lipsum[1-12]
\section{Test Section Two}
\lipsum[1-12]

\end{document}
```

The above examples will change the behaviour for all `\section` commands in the document; if the changes are moved from the preamble to the body, the changes will only apply from the point the code appears on (and you can restore the original definition if needed at some latter point). In the following example. the first and fourth sections behave as the default ones, but the second and third sections start on their own page and add additional vertical space:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[top = 1in, bottom = 1in, left = 1.5in, right = 1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum}% just to generate text for the example

\title{The Title}
\author{The Author}

\begin{document}

\maketitle
\section{Introduction}
\lipsum[1-12]

% change to \section
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\section{\clearpage\vspace*{1in}\@startsection {section}{1}{\z@}%
                                   {0ex \@minus -.2ex}%
                                   {2.3ex \@plus.2ex}%
                                   {\normalfont\Large\bfseries}}
\makeatother
\section{Test Modified Section One}
\lipsum[1-12]
\section{Test Modified Section Two}
\lipsum[1-12]

% restore the original meaning of \section
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\section{\@startsection {section}{1}{\z@}%
                                   {-3.5ex \@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex}%
                                   {2.3ex \@plus.2ex}%
                                   {\normalfont\Large\bfseries}}
\makeatother
\section{A Test Regular Section}
\lipsum[2]

\end{document}
```

Of course, if these changes are to be used many times, the use of wrapping newly defined commands would simplify the writing.

Comment: It seems to work now, but not without running through very many errors that I don't understand...

Comment: @bopgah your comment as it is is useless. Without a description of the errors and a MWE allowing us to reproduce them, nothing can be done. Please add the required information as an edit to your original question.

Comment: @bopgah a MWE is a "Minimal Working Example"; i.e., a minimal, yet complete document allowing us to reproduce the problems mentioned. Further information can be found in (I've just been told I have to write a minimal example, what is that?)[http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/3954] and in [What is a minimal working example?](http://www.minimalbeispiel.de/mini-en.html). Please notice that I've added a second solution to your problem not requiring any additional packages; you can try this solution.

Comment: The second solution works great. The only problem is that it also adds a page between the title and the introduction section. Is there a way either to take away that extra page in this one case, or to not add the new page automatically and instead I can add a \newpage before each section?